# Not able to build syntaxNet source?

Tags: python, tensorflow, syntaxnet

I did everything given in their [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet#installation) but I'm getting this error again and again....I tried googling and finding if anyone got the same error but nopes, didn't work out. Heres the command --

```
bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names \
syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
```

And heres the error -

```
ERROR: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package 'external': Extension file '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl' may not be loaded from a WORKSPACE file since the extension file is located in an external repository.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.052s
ERROR: Couldn't start the build. Unable to run test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a very useful script for installation on ubuntu-14.04
https://github.com/JoshData/models/blob/b72274d38f169f77e6a15e54834f463f627dc82a/syntaxnet/build/ubuntu-14.04_x64.sh

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it, it was related to the `bazel` version.

I had installed it before, so the version was 0.1.5. But in the docs, its written supported ones are 0.2 - 0.2.2b. I tried to upgrade it using brew but it didn't work.

So I tried to directly install it using the 0.2.2b installer and it worked :)